# ElasticSearch Queries in Grafana for JMeter Logs

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, lucene, jmeter, grafana

I am trying to build a JMeter Dashboard in Grafana. Instead of using InfluxDB, I am using ElasticSearch as the data source.

I am able to get the data, but I am unable to write proper [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org) queries to build all the tables that come with the JMeter 3.0 report.

Has anyone experimented and been able to build dashboard writing Lucene queries in [Grafana](http://grafana.org) for building a JMeter live test dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information but I'm going to try :).

> I am able to get the data, but I am unable to write proper Lucene queries to build all the tables that come with the JMeter 3.0 report.

I'll assume you are either not getting the correct documents for your statistics, or not getting the right statistics for your documents.

For the former you have to make sure your Elasticsearch (ES) is indexing your JMeter logs as "expected": for example, your String-typed ES fields like the sample label might be getting [analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html). Your search/Lucene queries are getting analyzed themselves, too.

For the latter you have to watch out for Grafana not retrieving the right statistics from ES. I myself have been experimenting with it recently: for example, I wasn't able to make a Percentile column in a table, simply because  [Grafana isn't retrieving that metric](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3786) from ES in tables as of 4.0.

Maybe you should specify what it is exactly that isn't working, then I'd be able to go into more detail...

Comment: Do you think it is possible to write queries which would help us calculate the percentile from the Lucene queries?